# ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails for existing tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am getting following error while assigning foreign key to existing table column:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`c_x_parsing`.`#sql-787_1`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-787_1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`nct_id`) REFERENCES `cdb` (`nct_id`))

Below is the my query:

```
ALTER TABLE c_int ADD FOREIGN KEY (n_id) REFERENCES cdb (n_id);
```

While my parent table is cdb cdb and child table is c_int.

Please suggest me the solution as I already tried with following commands:

```
ALTER TABLE cdb ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE c_int ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 16):

The issue is not the command, but the data. There's a value in the child table that does not exist in the parent table.

Try using something like this to figure out which data is causing the issue:

```
SELECT n_id FROM c_int WHERE n_id NOT IN (SELECT n_id FROM cdb)
```

Comment: You are right. There are some ids missing in parent table which are present in child table. Is there any way out by which I can do samething by ignoring ids which are present in child table but not in parent table or DO I have to repopulate the tables?

Comment: What you're suggesting would mean your foreign key would not be valid. What you could consider is creating a unqiue id for the 'unknown' or otherwise unimportant entries, and then updating the child table to ensure all other entries point to the new id.

Comment: I did have the same. Works as charm for me.

Comment: Using the example, ```REMOVE FROM c_int WHERE n_id NOT IN (SELECT n_id FROM cdb)``` worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

it seems there are some records in c_int table which their `n_id` values are not available on cdn table.

I suggest two solution

**first one disable constraint checking**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER TABLE c_int ADD FOREIGN KEY (n_id) REFERENCES cdb (n_id);
```

**Second remove or update those data**

```
delete FROM c_int WHERE n_id NOT IN (SELECT n_id FROM cdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the collation and charset of both the fields.
cdb(n_id) and column from parent table

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLAlchemy and before upgrading, you can adjust the last migration version as shown:

```
from alembic import op

def upgrade():
  # Disable foreign key checks
  op.execute('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;')
  # The rest of the migrations
  # ...

def downgrade():
  # The rest of the migrations
  # ...
```

then do the upgrade `flask db upgrade`